# is there any actual difference between aws ec2 service and aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

what is the actual difference between amazon web services ec2 and aws lambda, i have used ec2 and also read about lambda but couldn't find anything worth. 
Can you someone pl tell me what exactly the difference is

Answer (score 1):

**An Amazon EC2 instance is a virtual machine.** It is like a normal computer — it runs an operating system (Windows or various types of Linux), you can connect to it and use it. You can install normal software packages and run it for as long as you like. You are charged per-second while the instance is 'running'.

**An AWS Lambda function is a piece of code that is triggered to run.** Behind the scenes it runs on a "container", which is an extra layer of virtualization that makes it very fast. There is no operating system because the container platform takes care of that layer. Put simply, something triggers the Lambda function, the function runs, then it exits.

A Lambda function typically only runs for a few seconds (or even less than a second!). It does something in response to an event, such as a request being sent to AWS API Gateway or a file being uploaded to Amazon S3. It is intended for doing a very simple task (that you write), and then it exits. For example, when you run a Weather app on your mobile phone, the app makes a call to a web service on the Internet. It might trigger a Lambda function that retrieves the weather from a database and returns the information. It might run for only half a second.

AWS takes care of the platform on which a Lambda function runs. You simply supply the code, configure a trigger and that's it! Whether your code runs once a month or 30 times a second, AWS Lambda will take care of deploying and running the function. This concept is known as **serverless computing** since you just worry about the code, not the server.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research this is what i understood, pl upvote if anyone finds it useful

The easiest way to look at this is to imagine EC2 as a virtual server, running an operating system, provisioned with storage, memory and CPU. And you pay for the specs over time. I.e. the bigger the server and the longer you have it on, the more you pay.
Lambda is a serverless service that executes your code based on events and triggers. It's a function, if you like, that performs your tasks in response to something happening. E.g. you could have a lambda function to resize JPG files as they are uploaded to S3.
Of course you could also build a EC2 server running similar code to do the same thing, but the os overhead and costs mean a simple Lambda function would be much more efficient and it footprint in the cloud, the resources used to run the code, a lot smaller.

Answer (score 0):

AWS EC2 is IaaS, think it as running a virtual machine or running a server on the cloud. With EC2 you have more control but you have more work to do like patching, maintaining etc. When you use ec2 you have to pay for running the instance (server) even-though your code might not get executed at least once.

AWS Lambda is a different technology to EC2 which is server-less, basically you are just running the code without explicitly running a server.  Think it as just uploading your code to cloud and AWS is running the server for you. You don't have to pay for the server, but the no of time your code got executed.